# Pass path to text file in Java jar to a C library?

Tags: java, jar, jna

I have a Java jar file that contains a text file. From the Java code within the jar I am using JNA to call functions in a C library. I need to pass a filepath to the text file to one of the C functions, so that the C program can read it.

Since it is the C program and not the Java program that needs to read the file, I can not simply do this:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("MyFile.txt");
```

The C program is not under my control, and it does not understand a `jar:file://` path.

How can this be done? Is the content of the jar automatically extracted somewhere? Do I need to extract it somewhere? How can I do that, when I can not be sure I have writing permissions anywhere?

Comment: If possible, I'd put that file somewhere on the filesystem, not into a jar. That would make client code (your C program) easier to understand. And a file into a jar is most likely something internal (developpers of the jar may not be well aware that this resource is used by somebody else, leading them to rename or delete this file with no considerations to other code involved). It would make updates of the file easier as well (you need not to release a module to update a config file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is evidently packed in the jar (or class path): that is meant by *resource*.

If you take the URL:

```
getClass().getResource("MyFile.txt");
```

one receives an URL like:

```
"jar:file://...path-to-jar... .jar! ...package-path-of-class.../MyFile.txt"
```

The C part has to unzip that entry from the jar (jar is a zip), and then you are done. Mind the "jar:file:/".

If the C part cannot be changed, create a temp file

```
Path path = Files.createTempFile("temp_", ".txt");
Files.copy(getClass().getResourceAsStream("MyFile.txt", path));
```

These functions can have additonal Parameters, file attributes.
And pass `path.toString()`.

Delete it as appropriate.

Comment: No problem, `Files` has some fine utility functions.